# Is it possible to send GET requests without waiting for response in iOS?

Tags: ios, get, ethernet

Waiting for response takes about 300ms , so i can send only 3-4 requests per second to my custom device, its to slow, i'm working on improving the speed of "user interaction".

Now i'm using this code:

```
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:0.5];
    NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: What is stopping you from using `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler`? Just make sure you don't send asynchronous requests so close toghether that your custom device couldn't handle them all.

Comment: Nice idea, i'll try to find some more info how to use it

Comment: Just added an 'answer' - you'd still need to do the real coding but the basic idea would work and the sequence makes sure that your device handles all the requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fire requests asynchronously properly implementing `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler`

Let's say you wan't to fire a set of requests every 5 seconds. You can implement a repeating timer that issues first request. You could make request delegates issue requests in sequencial order (each delegate issues the next request). In very simplified meta language it would look like:

```
- repeatingTimer5sHandler {
    issue1stRequestWithHandler:handlerFor1stRequest;
}

- handlerFor1stRequest {
    handle response
    issue2ndRequestWithHandler:handlerFor2ndRequest;
}

- handlerFor2ndRequest {
    handle response
    issue3rdRequestWithHandler:handlerFor3rdRequest;
}

- handlerFor3rdRequest {
    handle response
    issue4thRequestWithHandler:handlerFor4thdRequest;
}

- handlerFor4thRequest {
    handle response
}
```

At the bottom of [this page](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/95478-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-blocking-ui.html) is a working solution. It's only for one request but it should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the problem is when user is changing progress bar value and this value is sending to custom device, it goes roughly and slowly. Is there an opportunity so create something like "data flow" to make this smoothly as everything in the iOS devices?

Comment: progress bar itself goes roughly, now I'm using value changed action, may be to use another or send data every 200 m. seconds or smth else?

Comment: @HorheGarcia: i'm not sure if i understand you correctly. If you mean data flow like streaming then that would be one way 'communication'. If you're talking about two-way communication you could speed up using TCP sockets directly - it would require more work from your side. And again there's a question if you can cotrol the firmware (behaviour) of this custom device - is that your design or something of-the-shelf.

Comment: @HorheGarcia: as for 200ms: it's possible but it depends on latencies and the quality of the network the devices are in. And of the speed of the custom device. You really should wait for the device to respond to the request before submitting another. If you can join all the requests to one single instance - then again you could speed things up. 'Seamless' TCP data exchange usually takes a lot of experimenting and thinkering. But it's usually doable at the end :)

Comment: i tried   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:quququ completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *respons, NSData *data, NSError *error) { //do smth
               }]; it seems to work the at the same speed as synchronous;

Comment: @HorheGarcia: you're welcome. And good luck with your project!

Comment: Yes, u have understood me right, i need one way communication like streaming. What do u think a best way to do it? Yes, I'm also making a firmware for custom device its based on microchip TCPIP stack.

Comment: @HorheGarcia: the speed is probably maximum that TCP protocol can give you. The plus of asynchronous request is that your user interface doesn't block. If you carefully plan things (or usually later by lots of experimental work) your app-flow will look seamless. But the only way to achieve this is going asynchronous. :)

Comment: @HorheGarcia: i made one project with iPad and Microchip's MRF24WB0MB/RM controlled by PIC24FJ256GA106 (AdHoc wireless). The most i could get out of this was 200b packets every 0.1s but reliability depends a lot on the qualitiy of the wireless link. Is your custom device server or client?

Comment: its something like web server. so its slowly because of my device?

Comment: @HorheGarcia: Actually it's because TCP protocol is made more for reliability and not for speed. I got the best results using [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/1954) for creating iOS client code. If you really have a need for speed you might want to consider some kind of streaming (maybe even UDP?). I don't have much experience on this field.

Comment: @HorheGarcia: i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: sorry for that, i wanted to say if on "stack overflow" is any social-network like section 'friends' or smth..

Comment: @HorheGarcia: no problem - i don't think so. Although it's true that in time you find yourself communicating with some people more than with others :)